# Can't understand why this equation is arranged this way

Tags: probability

Given the following:

[image]

I can't understand how the equation moved from the left to right. How come the given term | can just be swapped around, and a new variable added outside. What probability rule is this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the conditional probability rule, the one we are used to seeing as

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$$

but that can easily be extended to

$$P(A \cap B|C) = P(A|B,C)P(B|C)$$

In your example though, I suspect there is something you are not mentioning, and that is the conditional independence of $z^{(i)}$ with respect to $p$. Not having additional information, that is what I can assume. If this were not the case, then the transition from the left to right hand side would be

$$\prod_{i=1}^NP(x^{(i)},z^{(i)}|\pi,p) = \prod_{i=1}^NP(x^{(i)}|z^{(i)},\pi,p)P(z^{(i)}|\pi,p)$$